# window.location does not execute with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="social" id="social">Link one</a> 
<a href="www.cnn.com" class="social" id="social">Link two</a> 
<a href="www.facebook.com" class="social" id="social">Link three</a>
```

I'd like to be able to have the user:

1. Click on a link
2. Have the links href store into the `$href` variable
3. After the user has chosen from the checkboxes, take the user to the
   `$href` location.

I've been working with [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jg8jT/19/).

So how do I get the links to go to their respective locations upon checkbox selection?

If anyone could offer any help or suggestions; I'd really appreciate it Thanks!

```
p{
    display: inline-block;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label{
    opacity: .5;
}
.faded{ color: grey;
    opacity: .5;
}

<p>Links should go to their respective locations upon checkbox selection</p>
<br>

<a href="www.google.com" class="social" id="social">Link one</a> 
<a href="www.cnn.com" class="social" id="social">Link two</a> 
<a href="www.facebook.com" class="social" id="social">Link three</a> 

<div class="know-your-role">
    <div id="checkwrapper">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <p>Are you a</p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-1"  class="checkchoice student" value="1"><label for="check-1" class="choice student tooltip" title="Student">Student</label>
            <p>or</p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-2" class="checkchoice teach" value="2"><label for="check-2" class="choice teach tooltip" style="padding-right: 20px;" title="Teacher">Teacher</label>
            <p>?</p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="style-select type">
        <input type="text" placeholder="What year" />
    </div>
    <p class="faded">       
     "What year" input should only appear when student is selected'
    </p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.type').hide(); 
$(".know-your-role").hide();


$(".social").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".wizard").hide();
    $('.know-your-role').show('fast');
    var $student = $('input:checkbox.student');
    var $teach = $('input:checkbox.teach');

    if($student.is(':checked') & $(".year").va() != ""){
        window.location.href = href;
    }else if ($teach.is(':checked')){
        window.location.href = href;
    }
});

$(function(){
    $('#check-1').change(function() {
        $('#checkwrapper').hide();
        $('.type').css('width','110px')
        $('.type').show();
    });
});

$('input:checkbox.checkchoice').click(function(){
    var $inputs = $('input:checkbox.checkchoice');
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true);
    }else{
        $inputs.prop('disabled',false);
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe you need to put all your code in a $(function (){});

Comment: @Ibu I had tried that before, it still failed to execute window.location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="social">Link one</a> 
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" class="social">Link two</a> 
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="social">Link three</a>
```

Ids must be unique, and href must be preceded by `http://`

```
if($student.is(':checked') & $(".year").va() != ""){
```

The correct syntax is `val()` not `va()`

http://jsfiddle.net/knoxzin1/Jg8jT/20/

----------------------- EDITED ---------------------------------------

http://jsfiddle.net/knoxzin1/Jg8jT/29/

Now working as OP asked

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I don't know what you mean by 'ids must be unique'. What Ids?

Comment: `id="social"` you have this in all `a` elements, the id attribute should be unique in all html page

Comment: Oh so you're saying for $('#social').each(function (){ // do stuff }?

Comment: I'm not a jquery pro by any means so please excuse my n00bie-ness

Comment: No you don't have to do `$('#social').each(function (){}` because ids are `unique` its the same as `$("#social")`, check the fiddle and see if your code is working fine

Comment: Oh I see! Well it seems that even with the set id: The `window.location` still fails to execute after a checkbox is checked. (And for the second link it just goes to the link)

Comment: This is because `jsfiddle` use iframes, some sites such as facebook dont allow iframes

Comment: After applying the fixes to my local. The window.location still fails. Is it because I have to submit or anything of the sort?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26396/discussion-between-rodrigo-assis-and-modelesq)